# How can I create a share or like button so that site owners can put it on their sites which will post back to my site?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, api

How can I create a share or like button so that site owners can put it on their sites which will post back data to my site? Kinda like what the social sites do like twitter and digg?

Was wondering if anyone could give me the low-down on the topic or some direction into what I should be looking for?

Answer (score 1):

don levelest way: use a simple form/imagebutton with a get and let the site owners fill the parameters of the url.

offer this code:

```
  <form method="get" action="http://urlofyourpage?param1=28&ref=urlofsharesite">
      <input type="image" 
        name="fancy" 
        src="foo.jpg" 
        title="click to share this page"
       />
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I've seen some sites do is create an image that lives on their server and then they post a short snippet of markup that displays the image, surrounded by  tags that refers back to their own site.

So for example:

```
<a href="www.mywebsite.com" target="_blank">
  <img src="/MyContent/MyImages/MyLogo.png" alt="Come visit my site!" />
</a>
```

It could be as simple as that, however I have also seen some cases where the markup is referring to a script that tracks where the person is coming from as well.

Answer (score 0):

visit addthis.com, this is free to use for everyone, you can customise the icons too. It gives you an easy code all you do is just copy and paste, also can edit the code to show the sites you want. I think this website is good as sony ericsson website are using this from addthis.com.

Comment: Great tool but what I want to do is to be able to allow people to share stuff to my site